# Unable to set UIImage, always returns nil

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

This is probably a ridiculous question but I just can't figure it out for the life of me. I have a class which subclasses NSObject which has a property called image setup, like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

Somewhere else I initialize the class and attempt to set the image in the class, like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test"];
Class *item = [[Class alloc] init];
item.image = image;
```

But when I try to call item.image it is always nil.
The image called Test is in the project and is used elsewhere so I know it has access to the image, but for some reason it isn't being copied to the instance of my class. I have put NSLog messages and breakpoints directly after setting the image which have shown it to be nil as well as using commands via the debugger which have also shown the image in the class to be nil while the UIImage I create to copy is not nil.

I know I am doing something wrong but I have searched and can't figure out what it is.

Thanks for looking, any help is much appreciated.

edit:

I am trying to access the image from a method inside of the class.

```
- (void)save {
     if (self.image != nil) {
       // do some stuff
     } else {
       NSLog(@"image is nil");
     }
   }
```

And it is always coming up nil.

edit 2:
Thanks again everyone. I figured out what the problem was. I was overriding the setters/getters which was causing the issue.

Comment: How are you "calling" item.image? Please post that code.

Comment: You still haven't provided enough info... For example, what code are you using to call `save`? And don't just include the single line of code... How are you accessing the updated instance of `Class`?

Comment: Try including the file extension.  Also depending on the device you are running on, you may need a @2x retina version.  I would also make sure that when you select the file in the project, that there is a checkmark next to your target in the inspector.

Comment: @JoshGafni "The image called Test is in the project and is used elsewhere so I know it has access to the image"

Comment: Show your 'Class' code to me. I think your Class code have error.

Comment: So it works elsewhere in the code... just not in this one place?

Comment: other considerations: `imageNamed:` isn't guaranteed to be thread safe, so I guess it's possible that if some other piece of code is doing something to it that would cause this to return nil... perhaps that's a stretch though.

Comment: So basically, you still need to include more of your code...

Comment: Thanks for input, I'm on my phone responding to this but I'll post more as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: What is the full image name? If the extension is not ".png" you need to specify the entire file name including the extension. Also how is it used elsewhere, code please.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a .png file? Try doing it like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.png"];
```

Comment: From Apple docs: "On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension."